# No software in Ubuntu 16.04 Software Center

Tags: software-center

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 a few days ago.

However, I couldn't see any software apart from the already installed software.

Ubuntu Software Center just isn't showing any software.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me after using BleachBit with root access. Installing another language fixed the issue. Maybe it'll work for you, too.

Steps are as follows.

Open **Language Support** and Install another language.
Language Support > Install/Remove Languages... > click any language you want and then apply.
Then go to the software center, go to the update tab and refresh it.

[image: Screenshot]